# AWS Load Balancer: changing A record

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have inherited a website that uses AWS for DNS and load balancing. However, the website will be migrated away to another server and won't need load balancing anymore. DNS will remain at AWS. I would like to ensure I remove and add the right DNS settings to make this happen.

Current A record in Route 53:

```
domain.com. ALIAS http://dualstack.site-loadbalancer-XXXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
```

This is the current record that I assume redirects to the load balancer. I don't see any TTL configured in Route 53 for this record but when I `dig` it consistently returns a 1 minute TTL. What I am planning to do is simply removing a record and adding a new A record instead:

```
domain.com. 111.222.333.444
```

I am not familiar enough with AWS to know if this would trigger any additional actions. I rather not touch the load balancer service at all; I simply want to direct traffic away to the new server.

Would this work or is there anything else I should take into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Alias is an internal pointer to another record in Route 53.  The value of the alias target is used to answer queries for the original record.

This is why, when you query for this record, you see IP addresses and a TTL that you didn't define.  AWS load balancers always use small TTLs.

Replacing this with an A record that is not an alias should do exactly what you expect, with no side effects elsewhere in AWS, because the load balancer does not track the DNS entries that are pointing to it.